# Generating random graphs with given properties

Tags: graph-theory, big-list, random-graphs

One way to define random graphs is to fix a finite set of properties $P$. Picking with equal probability a graph with $|V|=n$ out of the set $\Gamma_n(P)$ of all $n$-(vertex-)graphs with properties $P$ yields a random $n$-$P$-graph. This is the theoretical point of view. Practically, the set is not at hand and one has to *generate* with equal probability graphs that happen to be in $\Gamma_n(P)$.

The classical [Erdös-Renyi graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) $G(n,m)$ are defined like this with $P = \{|E| = m\}$. To generate an Erdös-Renyi random graph is easy.

[Configuration models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_model) allow to generate random graphs with a given degree distribution. [Advanced configuration models](https://www.pnas.org/content/99/suppl_1/2566) allow to generate graphs that in addition have a given distribution of the [clustering coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient).

My questions are:

- For which classes of random graphs (defined by a set of properties they must have) are there well known and efficient ways to generate them randomly? (This might be a big list question.)
- For which classes of random graphs are **no** ways known to efficiently generate them randomly?
- By which heuristic arguments can one tell whether for a given set of (non-contradictory) properties there may be ways to efficiently generate them randomly - or not?

Comment: Small bit of pedantry: presumably you want your set $\Gamma(P)$ to be finite and every graph in it to be generated with equal probability? Things get Complicated if $\Gamma(P)$ is allowed to be infinite...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Thanks, I made these assumptions explicit.

Comment: You might still want to clarify a little bit — $P$ can be finite without $\Gamma(P)$ being finite. (e.g., if $P$ is '$G$ is cubic'). Does it make sense in your context to specifically consider the set $\Gamma_n(P)$ of $n$-vertex graphs with the property $P$? (This would make the Erdös-Renyi graphs $\Gamma_n(P)$ with $P=\{|E|=m\}$, for instance.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Again you are right! I'll correct this later.

Comment: Another pragmatic facet of this is whether you want distributions that are exactly random or merely random within a certain tolerance. I'm having a hard time finding good references but I've seen [Metropolis-Hastings sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) used for sampling constrained configurations (e.g. colorings of a graph) where there are transforms that can take one valid configuration to another. See for instance chapter 2 of https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.110/lehre/ss15/StochasticSimulation/Lecture_Notes.pdf .

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I've done so.