# Properties that are assumed to hold for almost all graphs in a given class

Tags: probability, graph-theory, reference-request, big-list, random-graphs

For some classes of random graphs (e.g. [defined by a given set of independent properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4065521/generating-random-graphs-with-given-properties)) one can prove that some (dependent) properties hold for almost all of them.

[Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all#Meaning_in_graph_theory):

- Almost all graphs are asymmetric.
- Almost all graphs have diameter 2.
- Almost all [Erdős–Rényi graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) have a Poisson degree distribution.

I can imagine the case that

- one has defined some class $\Gamma$ of random graphs,
- one has generated a large number of such graphs by a random process, and
- one experimentally found out that almost all of them have some graph property $P$. But
- one has not been successful in *proving* that $P$ holds for almost all graphs in $\Gamma$.

Maybe this is only a fictious scenario and never occurred. Then it would be interesting to know why. Does a proof of holding almost certainly always lie open? In case it *did* occur, I ask for specific references: Which are examples of graph properties (in some given class $\Gamma$ of graphs) that are only *assumed* to hold for almost all graphs in $\Gamma$

Comment: @MorganRodgers: Sorry to hear that (that my question is unanswerably too broad). This is one type of classes of graphs I am specifically interested in: [graphs defined by a multi-set of tiles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386549/random-graphs-defined-by-a-set-of-tiles).

Comment: @MorganRodgers: Please note, that I didn't ask "why" proofs have not been found. And I am not asking for *arbitrary* things that seem to be true experimentally, but "only" for graph properties holding for almost all graphs (in some arbitrary class $\Gamma$). Furthermore, I asked for *specific* examples (references). Therefore I added the [big list] tag.